# URI must be a string or UriInterface

Tags: laravel, guzzle

```
private function setRequest()
{
    $vKey = $this->voltKey;
    $vId= $this->voltId;

    $this->client = new Client(
        [
            'base_uri' => $this->url,
            'headers' => [
                'vkey' => $vKey ,
                'vid' => $vId,
                'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
                'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            ]

        ]
    );
}

  private function setApiResponse($body = [])
{ 
    
    $this->response  = $this->client->request('put', 
        $this->url, ["body" => json_encode($body)]            
    );
    
        return $this;
}
```

Please am having server error from guzzle.. Please is there any thing wrong with this

```
'Accept'        => 'application/json',
```

Because the stack trace points to the line

Comment: what is `$this->url`?

Comment: I am capturing the url from env file and its getting it

Comment: it would seem it is not, check what the value of that property actually is (most likely `null`) ... also you don't want to access `env` from outside config files

Comment: Please, can I add you on a any social media so that you help out... This thing is really affecting me for the past two days now. Because even if I copy the url and replace it there... Its still the same error

Comment: I can assist you here ... you might need to check the stacktrace again to make sure this is the code causing the error and you don't have a different method or controller being called

Comment: Well, Any time I dd($this->url) it prints the url as correctly as its supposed to be

Comment: Truly, The line have no problem.. I just didnt know what is wrong. Since am frustrated I just mentioned the line it pointed the stack trace on

Comment: try to use `is_string()` to check if $this->url is a string or not

Comment: @lagbbox. I have fixed the error, I would love us to talk again using the previous means.. am no longer seeing the link we use to chat... And I need your help on clarification of something sir